# Why would the following JS code not terminate in a browser?

Tags: javascript, node.js, browser, event-loop

```
function foobar() {
  console.log('baz');    
  setTimeout(() => foobar(), 1000);
}

foobar();
throw new Error('terminate');
```

I would assume that the `foobar` function queues a callback that is executed after 1s, exits the stack and then the main function throws an error and things should terminate. However they don't if run in a browser.

Comment: Exactly. The callback would be executed after 1 second... if only there were no immediate `throw new Error` instruction, that terminates the program before this can happen.

Comment: @JeremyThille That part they understand. Their question is why it does **not** terminate when run in the browser.

Comment: I'm not certain, but (provided I understand your question) I am guessing that that the execution is halted on a task basis. the setTimeout creates a separate task that, when executed schedules another one ... Which kind of makes sense. You wouldn't want to permanently kill all script execution on a webpage because one of them had an error.

Comment: Ah, I get it now. I misunderstood the question. But I don't have the answer :)

Comment: I suppose the real question is about why things are different in browser and in Node.js. Added an explanation to my answer.

Comment: To me it is unclear what you are asking. So are you saying that the timeout should not run after the error is thrown?

Comment: It doesn't run in Node.

Answer (score 3):

It's even better illustrated by this example:

```js
let attempts = 10;
function foobar() {
  if (!attempts--) return; // make it stop!
  console.log('baz');
  setTimeout(foobar, 1000);  
  throw new Error('terminate');
}
foobar();
```

See, throwing an Error terminates execution of the current task, but doesn't terminate the browser [**event loop**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop). And event loop already has another task sitting in its queue - scheduled by setTimeout *before* Error has been thrown. Rinse and repeat.

---

Things are different in Node.js land, however: the very first uncaught exception basically stops execution of the whole **process**. That's the philosophy of Node - [**fail early**](https://rjzaworski.com/2015/01/javascript-async-exceptions-handling) - and, though [**questioned**](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/3253-as-a-node-js-novice-i-don-t-understand-why-uncaught-exceptions-are-so-dangerous.htm), it exists the way it is.

Still, with minor modifications you'll see the similar picture. Just add these lines to the script:

```
process.on('uncaughtException', function (err) {
  console.error('CAUGHT', err);
});
```

... and you'll see quite similar pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Be the JavaScript interpreter.

Let's see the list of tasks, the JavaScript interpreter have to do :

---

### TaskList

**[Execute main code]**

---

Now the interpretor execute the task, line by line.

Executing `foobar();` the JavaScript interpreter is going to push a new task in it's task list, which is containing the `setTimeout()` function to execute.

---

### TaskList

**[Execute main code (in progress)][Execute setTimeout function]**

---

Then when it reach the throw, it throw an error and terminate the actual task execution.

It takes the next task and execute it :

---

### TaskList

**[Execute setTimeout function (in progress)]**

---

Executing the `setTimeout` function, it pushes again a new task (the same it just executed).

And again, and again, and again, and again...

---

```js
    function foobar() {
      console.log('baz');    
      setTimeout(() => foobar(), 1000);
    }
    
    foobar();
    throw new Error('terminate');
```